# Docker - Permission denied to connect to socket with nginx

Tags: docker, nginx, flask, docker-compose, fastcgi

Im running docker with 2 services: nginx and a fcgi-socket for a flask-app.
When nginx is trying to connect to the socket it gives to following:

> [crit] 7#7: *1 connect() to unix:/usr/src/app/flaskapp-fcgi.sock
>   failed (13: Permission denied)

Docker-compose.yml:

```
version: "3"
services:
    app:
        build: app/
        volumes:
            - app-volume:/usr/src/app

    http_proxy:
        build: nginx/
        ports:
            - '80:80'
            - '443:433'
        depends_on:
            - app
        volumes:
            - app-volume:/usr/src/app
        restart: always

volumes:
  app-volume:
```

Dockerfile nginx:

```
FROM nginx
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
```

Dockerfile app:

```
FROM python:3.6.2-onbuild
CMD ["python", "app.fcgi"]
```

app.fcgi:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from flup.server.fcgi import WSGIServer
#flask app
from app import app

if __name__ == '__main__':
    WSGIServer(app, bindAddress='./flaskapp-fcgi.sock').run()
```

nginx.conf:

```
    ...

    server {
            root /usr/src/app/;

            listen 80 default_server;
            listen [::]:80 default_server;

            location / {
                client_max_body_size 10M;
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;

                include fastcgi_params;
                fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_script_name;
                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_NAME "";
                fastcgi_pass unix:/usr/src/app/flaskapp-fcgi.sock;
            }

            location /static { try_files $uri =404; }
            location ~ ^/(static|favicon.ico$|robots.txt$) { try_files $uri =404; }

    }
```

Comment: how is the socket being created? Post the dockerfiles

Comment: Try changing `WSGIServer(app, bindAddress='./flaskapp-fcgi.sock').run()` to `WSGIServer(app, bindAddress='./flaskapp-fcgi.sock', umask=0).run()`

Comment: @TarunLalwani dude, you saved my life! one week stuck on this trying so many different things, and yet the solution is so simple... I have more or less the same setup with a Flask app and this worked!

Comment: @Guillaume, thanks for sharing the feedback. The OP never shared the feedback and hence I never posted it as answer. Good to know it works. Now posted the same as an answer

Answer (score 3):

You need to use `umask=0` to make this work

```
WSGIServer(app, bindAddress='./flaskapp-fcgi.sock', umask=0).run()
```